# ifcfg-ethx file does not appear on adding a new network interface on VmWare

Tags: linux, networking, bonding

i want to ask that when you add an network interface on Centos 6.9 on vmware. Then why doesn't it produce a file like ifcfg-ethx in the directory /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts. Do we have to create a new file using vi editor for bonding purpose? any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Indeed after first installation, the files won't be created automatically.

Possible alternatives to set it up:

- manually writing the files using vi or other text editor
- network-manager if installed (nmcli....)
- /usr/bin/system-config-network (text-base UI)
- graphical settings on your desktop (if installed)

(maybe other exist... )